# Bazel Build Fails on AWS Ubuntu with C++ Standard Library and Include Path Errors

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, build, bazel

I have a C++ Bazel project that builds successfully on Windows, but when I try to build the same project on AWS Ubuntu using Bazel, I encounter several errors. The project uses the [nlohmann/json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) library for JSON handling and the [Abseil](https://abseil.io/) library. Here are the key error messages from the build output:

1. For `nlohmann/json.hpp`:

```
main.cc:12:10: fatal error: nlohmann/json.hpp: No such file or directory
   | #include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
   |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

2. For `graphcycles.cc` from Abseil:

```
external/com_google_absl/absl/synchronization/internal/graphcycles.cc: In member function 'void absl::synchronization_internal::GraphCycles::RemoveNode(void*)':
external/com_google_absl/absl/synchronization/internal/graphcycles.cc:451:26: error: 'numeric_limits' is not a member of 'std'
  | if (x->version == std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max()) {
```

The **nlohmann/json.hpp** file exists in a folder called nlohmann in the root of my project, and I have set up a cc_library rule in my Bazel BUILD file to include this directory. The build works fine on Windows, but these errors occur on AWS Ubuntu.

Here's the relevant part of my BUILD file:

```
cc_library(
    name = "json",
    hdrs = glob(["nlohmann/**/*.hpp"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"] )

cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.cc"],
    deps = [...],
    copts = ["/std=c++17"],  # Note: this option works on Windows )
```

I suspect the issue could be related to differences in handling include paths or the C++ standard version between Windows and Linux. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve these errors for a successful build on AWS Ubuntu would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One problem of your source is that only your Windows compiler understands "/std=c++17". On every other compiler on the planet you have to use "-std=c++17".

You can create a `.bazelrc`:

```
# GCC 11.3
build:gcc11 --cxxopt=-std=c++20

# Clang 14.0.0
build:clang14 --cxxopt=-std=c++20

# Visual Studio 2022
build:vs2022 --cxxopt=/std:c++20
```

Remove `copts = ["/std=c++17"],` and build than with a specific config, e.g. `bazel build --config=gcc11 //...` or `bazel build --config=vs2022 //...`

Three are also "predined" configs for `linux`, `macos` and `windows` you can use. This can be enabled by adding `build --enable_platform_specific_config` to your `.bazelrc` file.

You can then define defaults for different platforms e.g.:

```
build:macos --cxxopt=-std=c++2b # Use this standard on macOS
build:windows ... # Windows goes here
```

This allows you to use `bazel build //...` without defining a config, but still using different settings on Linux, Windows and macOS.

A cleaner solution is to use `config_setting` as abseil-cpp does, e.g.:

```
config_setting(
    name = "gcc_compiler",
    flag_values = {
        "@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:compiler": "gcc",
    },
    visibility = [":__subpackages__"],
)
```

Somewhere else - use a select to define compiler flags:

```
ABSL_TEST_COPTS = select({
    "//absl:msvc_compiler": ABSL_MSVC_TEST_FLAGS,
    "//absl:clang-cl_compiler": ABSL_CLANG_CL_TEST_FLAGS,
    "//absl:clang_compiler": ABSL_LLVM_TEST_FLAGS,
    "//absl:gcc_compiler": ABSL_GCC_TEST_FLAGS,
    "//conditions:default": ABSL_GCC_TEST_FLAGS,
})
```

In some test:

```
cc_test(
    ...
    copts = ABSL_TEST_COPTS,
    ...
)
```

Consult the abseil-cpp source for this.